# breeze saving entity with multiple keys

Tags: breeze

On server, EF mapping defines 2 keys for entity

```
HasKey(t => new { t.EpisodeId, t.ConsumerAdviceId });
```

Trying to save new entity from client

```
this.domainContext.newAddedEntity(EpisodeConsumerAdvice.typeName, {consumerAdviceId: consumerAdviceId, episodeId: this.episode.id });
```

everything saves correctly to db but

```
this._entityManager.saveChanges()
```

throws error "Internal Error in key fixup - unable to locate entity"

Comment: Dan, were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, seems FNG custom provider didn't account for composite key.  Instead of trying to fix that, it was easier to just fix the table by adding a single primary key and then unique constraint on the other 2 fk's.